# Checking a checkbox using jquery from another div using prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know why this is not working. I tried the same way as seen in some of the stackflow solutions but still not getting the image as well as the checkbox response.

```
<form>
<div class="col s12">
    <div style="display:none">
        <label for="Type">Type</label>
        <input type="hidden" id="Type">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type1" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="1">
            <label for="Type1">Fruits</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type2" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="2">
            <label for="Type2">Vegetables</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type3" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="3">
            <label for="Type3">Pulses</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type4" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="4">
            <label for="Type4">SeaFoods</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Food types</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons fruit"></span> <span class="iconname">Fruits</span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons vegi"></span> <span class="iconname">Vegetables</span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons pulses"></span> <span class="iconname">Pulses</span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons seaFood"></span> <span class="iconname">Sea Food</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form
```

JQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span.food-icons.fruit").click(function(){
        if($(".checkbox #Type1").prop("checked") == false){
            $('.checkbox #Type1').prop('checked', true);
            $("span.food-icons.fruit").css("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits1.png)";
        }
        else{
            $('.checkbox #Type1').prop('checked', false);
            $("span.food-icons.fruit").css("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits.png)";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you have missing `)` here ("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits.png)" should be ("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits.png)");

Comment: correct it and try again

Comment: Thank you so much. A brack spoilt my one day. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: One more thing, how will I ensure that the check function is working?

Comment: Always check your **developers console** if something is not working as expected or code breaks, it's better to use smart IDE...

Comment: When your code does not run at all, it means you have a syntax error in it. To find a syntax error use developer tools in your browser, there you can find the error type and position.

Comment: it works fine if you have doubts check this http://jsfiddle.net/en797xqw/

Answer (score 0):

Your clicking span.iconname not span.food-icons. wrap .iconname in .food-icons

You are also missing a closing bracket on you $.css selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".food-icons.fruit>.iconname").click(function(){
      console.log("click");
    if($(".checkbox #Type1").prop("checked") == false){
            $('.checkbox #Type1').prop('checked', true);
            $("span.food-icons.fruit").css("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits1.png)");
        }
        else{
            $('.checkbox #Type1').prop('checked', false);
            $("span.food-icons.fruit").css("background-image", "url(images/icons/fruits.png)");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12">
    <div style="display:inherit">
        <label for="Type">Type</label>
        <input type="hidden" id="Type">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type1" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="1">
            <label for="Type1">Fruits</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type2" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="2">
            <label for="Type2">Vegetables</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type3" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="3">
            <label for="Type3">Pulses</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Type4" checked="false" name="Type[]" value="4">
            <label for="Type4">SeaFoods</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Food types</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons fruit"> <span class="iconname">Fruits</span></span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons vegi"></span> <span class="iconname">Vegetables</span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons pulses"></span> <span class="iconname">Pulses</span></li>
        <li class="unchkd"><span class="food-icons seaFood"></span> <span class="iconname">Sea Food</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```